# Printer Driver - custom paper size

Tags: printing, driver, printers

I'm working on custom printer V3 driver.
The current task is to give ability to create custom paper size to user. I google it a bit and found 2 ways of doing that:

1) CUSTOMSIZE option in GPD file.
I've added this to my GPD file:

```
  *Option: CUSTOMSIZE
{
    *rcNameID: =USER_DEFINED_SIZE_DISPLAY
    *MinSize: PAIR(4724, 6992)      
    *MaxSize: PAIR(14032, 20410)    
    *MaxPrintableWidth: 14032
    *MinLeftMargin: 0
    *CenterPrintable?: FALSE
    *Command: CmdSelect
    {
        *Order: PAGE_SETUP.2
        *Cmd: ""
    }
}
```

, but could not find where it appears in UI.

2) also I found that some printers have custom dialogs which allow to create custom paper size.
For example:

[image]

Is it possible to create for V3 printer driver? If yes then how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible. If you added the custom size option to the GPD correctly then you should see custom size as an option in the paper size dropdown. It's up to your print driver to display the custom size dialog if the user selects that option. Take a look at this article. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Of course I read it, but have not found how to show this UI for choosing custom paper size. I don't have custom paper size in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Both ways work. To use customized (vendor-defined or user-defined) paper sizes (non-standard paper sizes) in V4 and V3 printer driver models, you can go through the following links but you need to develop some codes:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/unidrv-minidrivers

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/printer-features

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/customized-features

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/customized-options

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/specifying-paper-sizes

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/supporting-vendor-defined-paper-sizes

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/supporting-user-defined-paper-sizes

In V4 print driver model, changing .gpd file breaks the driver package sign and you will have difficulty to install your changed driver package in Windows Driver Repository. You have to re-sign the driver package that it does not look as simple as it sounds if you are not developing your own driver.

The second way is in fact provided by the driver vendor or developer using the first one. They include some GDL schema-based description in the .gpd file(s) of their driver to allow the end users to define their own custom paper size(s). For a clear and straight forward sample, see the last link above.

Comment: Please let me know if you have any similar solution implemented in V4.

Answer (score 0):

Custom size paper should be created by the user in "Print server properties" form.
It appeared in the paper size dropdown for the printer if fits minsize/maxsize and others.